# Using GitLab token to clone without authentication

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to clone GitLab repository without prompt for my automation script, by using my private token from my GitLab account.

Can someone provide me a sample?

I know I can do so with user and password:

```
git clone https://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + gitlaburl;
```

and I know it is possible with ssh key

But, both options are insufficient.

Comment: `git clone https://<token-name>:<token>@gitlaburl`

Comment: for me the usefull syntax was: https://$GIT_USERNAME:$GITLAB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlaburl

Comment: for me the usefull syntax was: https://pat:<token>@gitlab.com/org/proj

Answer (score 482):

This is how you do it:

```bash
git clone https://oauth2:ACCESS_TOKEN@somegitlab.com/vendor/package.git
```

Comment: This worked for me on GitLab 8.5.7 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Works here (GitLab Community Edition 8.16.5 064dab1)

Comment: It works! I wonder why on gitlab.com on project details they don't give the complete command syntax :-((

Comment: Works for Gitlab 10.4.4 but you need to make an `api` token. A `read_user` can only read repos under `/users`

Comment: If there is a `submodule` inside, which hosted under the same account, the `clone` will still prompt to type in username and password. Is there any workaround?

Comment: The `oauth2` portion is probably arbitrary. I put the name of the access token instead.

Comment: This worked for me, after create token with API permissions

Comment: How to use this over `ssh`?

Comment: This answer helped me a lot but a pratical example solved my problem. Supposing to use GitLab, the solution is "git clone https://oauth2:a3Fae3FaQty5aq@gitlab.com/pippo/projectname.git", where PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN = a3Fae3FaQty5aq and pippo = username. Hope it will be helpful

Comment: Even `read_api` and `write_api` permissions are not enough. You have to have `api`.

Comment: Gitlab dot com should have this on their landing page under "cloning your repo ? do this first"

Comment: On Gitlab 14.7 (probably earlier versions too) any username (even blank username) will do as well:

```git clone https://xxx:YOURKEY@your.gilab.company.org/group/project.git```

Change xxx for empty string or any of your choice

Comment: @EllaSharakanski - currently, using https access, the `read_repository` permission is sufficient in order to clone a git repository.

Comment: `git clone https://:TOKEN@your.gitlab.url/group/projet.git`

Comment: For people coming here in 2024 and wondering why this is not working... the create token dialog has a new dropdown called "Role". I think at least "developer" or higher needs to bee selected for this to work ️

Answer (score 140):

The gitlab has a lot of tokens:

- Private token
- Personal Access Token
- CI/CD running token

I  tested only the Personal Access Token using ***GitLab Community Edition 10.1.2***, the example:

```
git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${Personal Access Tokens}@gitlab.com/username/myrepo.git


git clone https://oauth2:${Personal Access Tokens}@gitlab.com/username/myrepo.git
```

or using username and password:

```
git clone https://${username}:${password}@gitlab.com/username/myrepo.git
```

or by input your password:

```
git clone https://${username}@gitlab.com/username/myrepo.git
```

But the **private token** seems can not work.

Comment: Note that private tokens were removed in favour of personal access tokens in GitLab 10.2: https://about.gitlab.com/2017/09/22/gitlab-10-0-released/#private-tokens

Comment: And about user+password+token? How to express all in one URL? Now my gitlab-software server use all, login and two-factor (or token).

Comment: what are the differences for `gitlab-ci-token`, `oauth2` and `x-access-token`? all of these 3 work for me.

Answer (score 60):

Use the token instead of the password (the token needs to have "api" scope for clone to be allowed):

```
git clone https://username:token@gitlab.com/user/repo.git
```

Tested against 11.0.0-ee.

Comment: For people Googling this: this is what you want if using Personal Access Tokens over HTTPS on gitlab.com.

Comment: Isn't it amazing that we have to find this here and not on the GitLab Docs page on Personal Access Tokens?

Comment: Thx for "the token needs to have "api" scope for clone to be allowed"!

Answer (score 53):

You can do it like this:

```
git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:<private token>@git.example.com/myuser/myrepo.git
```

Comment: this seems right but it always fails authentication for me :(

Comment: same to me: fatal: Authentication failed for

Comment: <private token> needs to be replaced with the CI runner's token, not the account's private token.

Comment: i think you should also be able to use your personal token right @tim

Comment: You can use the project specific ci token (enable builds, then go to the project/runners config).

Comment: but I host an gitlab server for myself and its version is 6.6.2. I only have private token. When I run the command git clone https://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + gitlaburl; I got error fatal: Authentication failed for . same as @vogash

Comment: It still works for me. @biolinh Did you try generating the personal access token with api scope, from the Acess Tokens section under user settings.

Comment: tested using personal access token, works as of 2019-03

Comment: This solution worked for me, the highest voted solution (using oauth2) did not work. Literally just changed from oauth2 to gitlab-ci-token and it started working

Answer (score 36):

If you already has a repository and just changed the way you do authentication to MFA, u can change your `remote origin` HTTP URI to use your new api token as follows:

```bash
git remote set-url origin https://oauth2:TOKEN@ANY_GIT_PROVIDER_DOMAIN/YOUR_PROJECT/YOUR_REPO.git
```

And you wont need to re-clone the repository at all.

Comment: `git clone https://oauth2:TOKEN@ANY_GIT_PROVIDER_DOMAIN/YOUR_PROJECT/YOUR_REPO.git` also worked for me, thank you!! I will Answer this thread with my correct solution.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the runners token for CI/CD Pipelines of your GitLab repo.

```
git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:<runners token>@git.example.com/myuser/myrepo.git
```

Where `<runners token>` can be obtained from:

```
git.example.com/myuser/myrepo/pipelines/settings
```

or by clicking on the `Settings icon -> CI/CD Pipeline` and look for Runners Token on the page

Screenshot of the runners token location:
[image: Screenshot of the runners token location]

Comment: Note: The runners token has been deprecated now.

Comment: @ArihantGodha source?

Comment: @miq see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html) (as of >= 8.12)

Comment: This format is now deprecated, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409700/using-gitlab-token-to-clone-without-authentication/47347515#47347515

Comment: Doesn't work from inside GitLab CI pipeline. But this line works:
`git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/...`

Comment: @Slawa It does, but the project you want to clone needs to allow that first. See Settings → CI/CD Settings → Token Access

Answer (score 15):

Many answers above are close, but they get ~`username` syntax for `deploy` tokens incorrect.  There are other types of tokens, but the `deploy token` is what gitlab offers (circa 2020+ at least) *per repo* to allow customized access, including read-only.

From a `repository` (or `group`), find the `settings` --> `repository` --> `deploy tokens`.  Create a new one.  A `username` and `token` field are created.  The `username` is NOT a fixed value by default; it's unique to this token.

```bash
git clone https://<your_deploy_token_username>:<the_token>@gitlab.com/your/repo/path.git
```

Tested on gitlab.com public, free account.

Answer (score 13):

Inside a GitLab CI pipeline the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` environment variable works for me:

```
git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/...
```

Source: [Gitlab Docs](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22723#note_32734856)

BTW, setting this variable in `.gitlab-ci.yml` helps to debug errors.

```
variables:
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
```

Answer (score 13):

One possible way is using a deploy token
(https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens).  After creating the token, use:

```
git clone https://<username>:<deploy_token>@gitlab.example.com/tanuki/awesome_project.git
```

as mentioned in the link above.

Comment: Neither does this seem to be working with npm install on a fresh docker container, defaults to ssh.

Answer (score 10):

As of `8.12`, cloning using `HTTPS` + runner token is not supported anymore, as mentioned [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22484#note_15913305):

> In 8.12 we improved build permissions. Being able to clone project using runners token it is no supported from now on (it was actually working by coincidence and was never a fully fledged feature, so we changed that in 8.12). You should use build token instead.
>
> This is widely documented here - https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html.

Comment: It isn't possible using runners tokens but is using personal access tokens. Please see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409700/using-gitlab-token-to-clone-without-authentication/47347515#47347515

Comment: @MuhanAlim I'd recommend no one to expose their whole account using access tokens. That's why they are called ***Private** Access Tokens*!

Comment: The question doesn't mention anything about making the key public, only how to use the key in place of a username and password for cloning. But that it is a good point, I would not recommend anyone use the keys anywhere that is public.

Comment: *automation script* implies that the whole procedure is not running locally. Probably somewhere where others also have access to.

Answer (score 8):

These days (Oct 2020) you can use just the following

```sh
git clone $CI_REPOSITORY_URL
```

Which will expand to something like:

```sh
git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ci-debug-trace.git
```

Where the "token" password is ephemeral token (it will be automatically revoked after a build is complete).

Comment: How does it know the repository URL that you want? Seems like this would only work in CI/CD for the current repo.

Answer (score 5):

To make my future me happy: [RTFM](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html#before-gitlab-812) - don't use the gitlab-ci-token at all, but the `.netrc` file.

There are a couple of important points:

1. `echo -e "machine gitlab.com\nlogin gitlab-ci-token\npassword ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc`
2. Don't forget to replace "gitlab.com" by your URL!
3. Don't try to be smart and create the .netrc file directly - gitlab will not replace the `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` within the file!
4. Use `https://gitlab.com/whatever/foobar.com` - not `ssh://git@foobar`, not `git+ssh://`, not `git+https://`. You also don't need any CI-TOKEN stuff in the URL.
5. Make sure you can `git clone [url from step 4]`

Background: I got

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.mycompany.com': No such device or address
```

when I tried to make Ansible + Gitlab + Docker work as I imagine it. Now it works.

Comment: I really like this answer as it doesn't require changing the git repo URL in any way. This is super useful if you have an install script where it is difficult or unwanted to change the URLs.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I just provided the **token** *instead the password* (second input field).

[image]

I pushed a local repo for the first time from the command line.

From the scratch, these are the commands I entered (remember to move inside the repo's folder first).

```
$ git init

$ git status

$ git add .

$ git status

$ git commit -m 'Shinra Tensei.'

$ git push --set-upstream https://gitlab.com/userName/my-repo.git master
```

Then, the pop-up message you can see in the picture comes up. Provided USERNAME and TOKEN.

Comment: thank you so much, your answer helped me

Answer (score 4):

Using PAT (Personal Access Token):

```
https://pat:<your-token>@gitlab.com/<org>/<proj>
```

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation on this, but it works!

Answer (score 3):

I went SSH using the per project deploy keys setting (read only)

Comment: Me too because I am using GIT_STRATEGY: none.

Answer (score 1):

One issue I had here was the Project Access Token in private repo will not work if you select "Guest" when creating the token. Using "Reporter" or any other solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your:

```
user:oauth2
password : <youraccesstoken>
```

example:

```
git clone https://oauth2:<token>@hahahehe.com/yourname/yourproject.git
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help:
In your gitlab-ci file:
Add this on before script step

```
before_script:
  - git config --global credential.helper store
  - echo "https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}" >> ~/.git-credentials
  - chmod 600 ~/.git-credentials
```

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Customising the URL is not needed. Just use a git configuration for gitlab tokens such as

```
git config --global gitlab.accesstoken {TOKEN_VALUE}
```

[extended description here](https://www.bizmate.biz/news/it-articles/gitlab-clone-private-repository-with-access-token/)

Comment: This did not work for me and I also couldn't find documentation anywhere on a config option with this name

Comment: Have you read the article in the link? This variable is what gitlab will take from your git client to authenticate and you need a personal access token.

Comment: I did read the linked article. `gitlab.accesstoken` does not do anything and there is no documentation anywhere on GitLab referencing it