# how to use private GitLab repository as npm dependency with private token through https

Tags: node.js, https, npm, gitlab

I'm trying to use a private GitLab repo as npm dependency in my node js app, with a private token key, something like this:

```
"dependencies": {
     "my-module": "git+https://<privateToken>:x-oauth-basic@<myGitLabURL>/<MyUser>/my-module.git"
}
```

when I run `npm install` I get errors about the git clone with `fatal: unable to access <git repo path>` with 443 Connection refused replies.

I couldn't find a lot of documentation of how to do this through https and not through ssh.
It seems like [it does work on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728665/how-to-use-private-github-repo-as-npm-dependency)

Anybody have experience with this on GitLab with Https?

Comment: I used this article and it worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728665/how-to-use-private-github-repo-as-npm-dependency

Comment: You need to register your public key in the "Deploy keys" of your project. Long time ago there where an url with a token that let you readonly https access (so npm install too) but it no longer works. It were something like "git+https://gitlab-ci-token:55c302991447875db1242a9e8bcd59@gitlab.com/user/project.git --branch 2.0.0". As far as I know, the only actual (and secure) way now is the "Deploy keys" way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use private Github repo as npm dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728665/how-to-use-private-github-repo-as-npm-dependency)

Answer (score 12):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29570677/633107) worked for me.

```
"my-module": "https://oauth2:<PersonalAccessToken>@gitlab.com/<group>/<repository-name>.git
```

You can create a Personal Access Token under User Settings->Access Tokens ([GitLab.com Link](https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens)).