# Pipenv fails to pick up secret token from github workflow

Tags: python-3.x, github-actions, pipenv

I have a github action CI configured to use pipenv to install a package from a private repository.
For reasons unknown, `pipenv install` command returns the following error:

```
FAIL
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:Command errored out with exit status 128:
 command: git clone -q 'https://****@github.com/<ORG>/<REPO>.git' /tmp/pipenv-_xaxkgk4-src/csci-utils
     cwd: None
Complete output (1 lines):
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://${SUPER_SECRET}@github.com': No such device or address
```

I'm expecting the pipenv file to read the variable from an .env file created during CI run. Following is the relevant github workflow config, which runs before pipenv executes:

```
- name: Create .env file
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          echo SUPER_SECRET=${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }} > .env
          cat .env
```

PS: Personal access token is the secret's name created under the current repository of the user. This is not the default Github-token.

Update: Am able to confirm that pipenv receives the correct secret, by modifying and print the secret to the log. So, this essentially changes the question to - why does `git clone` ask for password even when password-token is used ?

Comment: Regarding your question, not sure, but this was asked for Oauth about the password request. It might be a scope issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148841/github-clone-with-oauth-access-token

Comment: @astrochun thanks for the link; I did see it before and i'm currently using a personal access token - hence, this is more puzzling that this issue still occurs, because PATs have the broadest scope there is, afaik.

Comment: Another option, for private repo, is to store your private SSH key and pass that. That would avoid the password request. Though I prefer PATs for CI.

Comment: @astrochun keeping that as the last alternative. have just sunk too much time on PATs already; really want to figure out what went wrong.