# git ls-remote failed when using personal access token

Tags: git, github, vercel

I'm deploying my Vite's app through Vercel.

One of the dependencies is a private repository in the Github,
So I've created the personal token and provided it in the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "my-private-repo": "git+https://<personal_access_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/myusename/my-private-repo.git"
},
```

I've tried to build, Everything seems fine in the local
However, in Vercel build it's throwing me this:

```
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads https://<personal_access_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/myusename/my-private-repo.git
```

So I've found that `git ls-remote` is the actual problem

Here is when I run `git ls-remote` with token

```
git ls-remote https://<personal_access_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/myusename/my-private-repo.git
>>> remote: Invalid username or password
```

And here is when I run `git ls-remote` without token

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/myusename/my-private-repo.git
>>> 9a1daaf0faa44d30afd22121cb8da061d25d9044        refs/heads/main
```

How come `git ls-remote` only work when no credential is provided since this is a private repo? Isn't it weird for Github?

How I can solve this within Vercel config or Github config?

Comment: `<personal_access_token>:x-oauth-basic` is the wrong syntax here: the thing to the left of `@` in an https URL is `username:password`, not `password:authtype`. (GitHub will figure out the user name for you under the right conditions, including when using an oath2 token as in VonC's answer, so you can provide a fake user name there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come git ls-remote only work when no credential is provided since this is a private repo?

Because of your local credential helper which has cached credentials in it.

```bash
git config --global credential.helper
xxx 
# replace xxx by the actual value

# check what is cached with:
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git credential-xxx get
```

You can temporarily *remove* those with:

```bash
# replace 'You' with the account seen in the previous get command
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=You" | git credential-xxx erase
```

Then try again locally the `git ls-remote https://<personal_access_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/` command for testing.

As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69075459/6309), see also if the following syntax works better:

`git ls-remote https://oauth2:TOKEN@github.com/username/repo.git`

Comment: answer is a bit confusing. git config --global credential-helper gives me:
error: key does not contain a section: credential-helper

Comment: @kev Yes, thank you for the feedback. It was a typo, and I have edited the answer accordingly: `credential.helper`, not `credential-helper`