# SSH authentication with gitfn_clone (SAS function)

Tags: sas

I'm looking to set up a batch process using a [github deploy key](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys).

Registering a key using any of the following:

- `ssh-keygen`
- `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`
- `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -E sha512`

And running the following code:

```
%let dirOut = %sysfunc(pathname(work))/package;
data _null_;
  rc=GITFN_CLONE(
    "git@github.com:allanbowe/sasjscore.git",
    "&dirOut",
    "git",
    "",
    "/home/sasjssrv/.ssh/id_rsa.pub",
    "/home/sasjssrv/.ssh/id_rsa"
  );
  put rc=;
run;
```

Results in:

> ERROR: Return code from GIT is (23). ERROR: You're using an RSA key with SHA-1, which is no longer allowed. Please use a newer client or a different key type.
> Please see https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/ for more information.

[image: sas error from git_clone]

The following algorithms:

- `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521`
- `ssh-keygen -t ed25519`
- `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "mygithubemail@provider.com"`
- `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -E sha512`

Return `-3` from `gitfn_clone()` with the following message:

> ERROR: Failed to authenticate with the remote repository.

A regular `git clone` works fine with ALL of the keys:

```
git clone git@github.com:allanbowe/sasjscore.git
Cloning into 'sasjscore'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

I also tried with `git_clone()` (after noticing `gitfn_clone()` was deprecated) but, same result.

Any ideas?

```
55         %put %sysfunc(GIT_VERSION()) &=sysvlong &=sysscp;
0.27 SYSVLONG=9.04.01M7P080520 SYSSCP=LIN X64
```

Running Centos 7 as described [here](https://sasapps.io/sasjs-server-on-centos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The issue is the use of an older version of GIT in 9.4m7.**  This should be fixed in 9.4m8, and is already fixed in Viya 4.

Thanks to the support of several internal SAS employees (you know who you are!) I can document TWO steps to address.

The first - to fix in m7 - just apply the following two hotfixes:

- [I9R087](https://tshf.sas.com/techsup/download/hotfix/HF2/I9R.html#I9R087)
- [I9R088](https://tshf.sas.com/techsup/download/hotfix/HF2/I9R.html#I9R088)

Then, regenerate using an appropriate cypher, eg: `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521` and add that public key to github.

The second approach, which I didn't get round to trying as it would have meant creating a new github account, was to use OpenAuth Access Tokens.  More information on that [here](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148841/github-clone-with-oauth-access-token#42175489).

Many thanks, Danny / Alexey / David!

EDIT - further to @joe's comment, I provide the logs from the hotfixes (`/opt/sas9/SASHome/InstallMisc/InstallLogs`):

`base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R087_en_Install_preexec.log`:

```
Installation Date 17/10/22 15:36 / User ID sasinstaller / IP Address 44.44.44.44 / Host CentOS-79-64-minimal

Skipped Files
There were no files to be processed.

Added Files
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/libssh2.so.1.0.1
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/libssh2.so

Backup Files
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R087/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/libssh2.so.1

Changed Files
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/libssh2.so.1

Removed Files
There were no files to be processed.
```

`base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R087_en_Install_postexec.log`:

```
Installation Date 17/10/22 15:37 / User ID sasinstaller / IP Address 44.44.44.44 / Host CentOS-79-64-minimal

Added Files
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/libssh2.so.1.0.1
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/libssh2.so

Backup Files
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R087/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/libssh2.so.1

Changed Files
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/libssh2.so.1
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasv9.cfg

Removed Files
There were no files to be processed.
```

`base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088_en_Install_preexec.log` :

```
Installation Date 17/10/22 15:36 / User ID sasinstaller / IP Address 44.44.44.44 / Host CentOS-79-64-minimal

Skipped Files
There were no files to be processed.

Added Files
There were no files to be processed.

Backup Files
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugitfn
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_f
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_v
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_i
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_c
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_s
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_b
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_r
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_d
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_p

Changed Files
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugitfn
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_f
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_v
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_i
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_c
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_s
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_b
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_r
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_d
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_p

Removed Files
There were no files to be processed.
```

And `/opt/sas9/SASHome/InstallMisc/InstallLogs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088_en_Install_postexec.log`:

```
Installation Date 17/10/22 15:37 / User ID sasinstaller / IP Address 44.44.44.44 / Host CentOS-79-64-minimal

Added Files
There were no files to be processed.

Backup Files
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugitfn
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_f
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_v
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_i
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_c
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_s
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_b
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_r
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_d
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R088/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_p

Changed Files
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugitfn
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_f
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_v
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_i
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_c
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_s
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_b
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_r
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_d
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/uwugit_p
/opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasv9.cfg

Removed Files
There were no files to be processed.
```

After searching a bit harder I found this (showing only the extract due to log size) in file `IT_2022-10-17-16.17.52.log`:

```
2022-10-17 16:22:43    Controller - Marshalling deployment.xml to /opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R005/Metadata/en/deployment.xml
2022-10-17 16:22:43    InstallationTask - All constrainBy tests met: true
2022-10-17 16:22:43    EntryData - backed up /opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/libgit2.so to /opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R005/SASHome/en/SASFoundation/9.4/sasexe/libgit2.so
2022-10-17 16:22:43    InstallationTask - sasexe/libgit2.so (0 bytes) has been successfully Backed up
2022-10-17 16:22:43    InstallationTask - sasexe/libgit2.so (1180370 bytes) has been successfully Changed
2022-10-17 16:22:43    ExtractTask - Created uninstall zip metadata at /opt/sas9/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/installs/base_lax_9.4_M7_HFI9R005/Metadata/en/en_sasexe.xml
```

So - it would seem, the answer is yes!

EDIT 2 - further feedback (thanks, Sundaresh) has shown that the `-m PEM` option can avoid the git (23) error, eg:

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 256 -m PEM -C "you@mail.com"
```

Comment: Did they upgrade the version of libgit2 behind the scenes?  Or something more?

Comment: It seems yes - `sasexe/libgit2.so`, answer updated