# When was oauth2 authentication for command line introduced in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

In this SO answer [1] an OAuth2 access token is used on the command line to authenticate a git command.

```
git clone https://oauth2:ACCESS_TOKEN@somegitlab.com/vendor/package.git
```

How can I find out when this feature was introduced? Specifically when the ability to put **oauth2** as the username and an **access token** as the password was introduced in Gitlab, in what version?

Because some actions are not possible using the Gitlab API I'm falling back to JGit for some actions in my application. I would like to gracefully degrade my app depending on the version of Gitlab used by users.

[1] [using gitlab token to clone without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409700/using-gitlab-token-to-clone-without-authentication/29570677#29570677)

Comment: Because I can't post an answer: 
I tested almost all Gitlab versions and the answer is: 9.2.5. The ability to use oauth2 as a username has been introduced in Gitlab V9.2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested almost all Gitlab versions and the answer is: 9.2.5. The ability to use oauth2 as a username has been introduced in Gitlab V9.2.5.