# Gitlab - git clone failed both with ssh and https in macOS

Tags: git, github, gitlab, fatal-error, git-clone

My coworker grant me access to his repository as Master, then i clone it both with SSH and HTTPS, but it always failed :

```
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

i've been check my generated public key in `.pub` file and already inserted to my Gitlab account. 
and i'm also tried to clone a repository(from other owner), and it works! 
it's confusing.

have i missed something?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any other keys in the `.ssh` dir and also check the keys loaded into your ssh agent.

Comment: now it works, thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I found multiple issues. I am not an expert in this area, but here is a summary of the steps I took to resolve.  Hopefully it will be helpful:

#### Solving the HTTPS clone problem:

1. Clone was failing with the error above, and I was not being prompted for my username and password on the command line.
   Running clone with verbose flag

   `git clone --progress --verbose https://[my_gitlab_server]/[repo]/[project].git`

   showed git was pulling credentials from OSX Toolchain, which were apparently incorrect.  I disabled this using instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052602/disable-git-credential-osxkeychain).

   `sudo git config --system --unset credential.helper`
2. I was now getting username and password prompt, but got:

   *remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied remote: You must use a personal access token with 'api' scope for Git over HTTP.
   remote: You can generate one at https://[my_gitlab_server]/profile/personal_access_tokens
   fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://[my_gitlab_server]/[repo]/[project].git/'*

   So I created a Personal Access Token as instructed [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html).
3. I was not sure what to do with the token.  Turns out you can include it in the URL as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409700/using-gitlab-token-to-clone-without-authentication/29570677#29570677) (for me that looked like `git clone https://oauth2:[token]@[my_gitlab_server]/[project].git` ) or you can just paste the token at the command line prompt for 'password'.

I could now clone via HTTPS.

#### Solving the SSH clone problem:

The SSH clone was giving the same error as the HTTPS clone. Some [background on bash agents](https://superuser.com/questions/284374/ssh-keys-ssh-agent-bash-and-ssh-add) is helpful here.

1. I found my **~/.ssh/config** file in my user directory and verified the repo had an entry there.

   `Host [my_gitlab_server]/[repo]
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2`
2. I had multiple id-rsa files in the ssh directory, so I opened **id_rsa2.pub** (the one associated with my repo in the config file) and compared it to the key I found in my repo by navigating to the 'SSH Keys' tab in my 'Profile Settings'.  The keys were the same.

   (If you need help creating and viewing keys see the docs [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/).)

My keys were in place, but my SSH clone was still not working.

3. I thought there might be a problem with the config file or that my keys were no longer valid, so I bypassed the config file by manually adding the key to the current terminal session using instructions [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths).

   `eval $(ssh-agent -s)
   ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa2`

   This worked so I knew my key was valid.

   (By the way, to see the keys loaded into your agent run `ssh-add -L` and to see their fingerprints run `ssh-add -l`.)

The problem now was that I needed to use the **~/.ssh/config** file so I would not have to run `eval` and `ssh-add` every time I opened a new terminal window.

4. To troubleshoot I ran `ssh -Tvv git@[my_gitlab_server]` which successfully connected to my gitlab server, but using a key I didn't recognize.  In the output I noticed that the file **id-rsa2** was not searched.
5. Using information from ssh.com about [keys](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key/#sec-How-to-set-up-public-key-authentication-for-OpenSSH) and [ssh_config files](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/), I found the  the **/etc/private/ssh/ssh_config** file specifies which keys are used.  The defaults were:

   `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`

   I added my id_rsa2 key by running `sudo nano /private/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and adding this line:

   `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2`

This worked like a champ.

Overall its better to use a single ssh key with the default id_rsa name to avoid problems like this.

Comment: Thanks. For me, just the first step in "Solving the HTTPS clone problem" solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Could yo check your git globals are correct respect your GitLab account.

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your name"
$ git config --global user.email your@mail.com
```

I got some problems cloning when my data was wrong.