# Gitlab oauth2 access token cannot use git over http

Tags: oauth-2.0, gitlab

I successfully get the oauth2 application access token for gitlab user. And the scope includes read_repository. But I cannot git ls-remote or git clone my project using this access token as password. 
The error is `remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied`

Btw, F2A is not enabled for my gitlab CE server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using gitlab token to clone without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409700/using-gitlab-token-to-clone-without-authentication)