# Adding personal access token in Gitlab : What are the different token scope use cases?

Tags: gitlab

I am connecting my GitLab account to PyCharm and while creating the token access in GitLab, I was uncertain what are the practical uses.
I am very new to this so if someone can dumb this down, that would be appreciated.

[image: Limiting scopes of a personam access token]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to:

- limit the actions you can do with one PAT
- have several PAT for several usage
- easily revoke one PAT if compromised/not needed, without invalidating the others

As [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50981074/6309), if you intend to use a PAT as your GitLab password, you would need the "`api`" scope.
If not, "`read_repository`" or (if you don't need to clone) "`read_user`" is enough.
"`read_registry`" is only needed if your GitLab host docker images as a docker registry.

> What I don't understand is it allows me to select all at once

That is because each scope matches a distinct use case, possibly covered by another scope.
By selecting them all, you cover all the use cases:

- **`api`** covers everything (which is too much, as illustrated by [issue 20440](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/20440). GitLab 12.10, Apr. 2020, should fix that with [merge request 28944](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/28944) and a `read_api` scope)
- **`write`** (since GitLab 1.11, May 2019): "[Repository read-write scope for personal access tokens](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/05/22/gitlab-11-11-released/#repository-read-write-scope-for-personal-access-tokens)".
  Many personal access tokens rely on api level scoping for programmatic changes, but full API access may be too permissive for some users or organizations.
  Thanks to a community contribution, **personal access tokens can now be scoped to only read and write to project repositories – preventing deeper API access to sensitive areas of GitLab like settings and membership**.
- **`read_users`** and **`registry`** each address a distinct scenario

As mentioned in [gitlab-ce/merge_request 5951](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/5951#note_14760535):

> I would want us to (eventually) have separate scopes for `read_user` and `write_user`, for example.
>
> I've looked at the [OpenID Connect Core spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ScopeClaims) - it defines the profile, email, address, and phone scopes, which need to be accompanied by the openid scope.
>
> S**ince we can have multiple allowable scopes for a given resource**, my preference would be to leave the `read_user` scope here, and add in the openid and profile scopes whenever we're implementing OpenID compliance.
> The presence of other scopes (like `read_user` and `write_user`) shouldn't affect the OpenID flow.

Comment: What I don't understand is it allows me to select all at once. So to use an analogy, say you had the option to issue read/write && read-only permission to a user pertaining to file X. If I issue read/write then also issuing read-only would be redundant. Of those scopes that are listed, is there a not a union between them?

Comment: @DonPowell I have edited my answer to address your comment.